# Extract a particular line from gziped file without uncompressing it

Tags: gzip

I have a huge gzip file of size 30 Gigs, I would need to extract a particular line from that file into a new file without uncompressing the giant file, say line 300021. Is there a way to do that ? if yes how?

Comment: I'll check back here later as that is an interesting question indeed. I think it's most likely that is not possible, and if that is indeed the case, I would recommend splitting that file up, having x number of lines per file for example, and gzipping that instead.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. There's nothing in a compressed file that provides info about the structure of the original data. gzip doesn't know anything about lines, it just treats the file as binary data.

Comment: I want to say that [perl has a module](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::gzip) that can read data line-by-line out of a compressed file, but (a) I've never used it and don't know the specifics and (b) this is beyond the scope of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

No. Not unless the gzip file had been specially prepared for this purpose, or you had built an index to the gzip file, which requires decompressing the whole thing once to build it. The best you could do would be to decompress it up to the point of the line you're looking for, and then stop after you get the line. At least then you wouldn't have to have space for the whole uncompressed gzip file, but it would still take, on average, half as long as it would take to decompress the whole thing.

You can find an example of building such an index to a gzip file in [zran.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c). Once you have the index, you can start decompressing at the index points, for which you select the span between them. In your case you would also want to include an index to the line starts, which would map where each, by number, starts as an offset in the uncompressed data.